# Not able to read files content inside NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some markdown files inside `/markdown` folder. I am trying to read content of these files. I can see the file names inside the array. But when I try to read it, it doesn't return any data or error. What needs to be done here?

```js
app.get("/", async(req, res) => {
  const mdPath = "...path"
  const data = await fs.readdirSync(mdPath);
  console.log(data) // Return Array of files
  for (let i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {
    const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(i, "utf-8");
    return fileContent;
  }
})
```

Comment: The return value isn't evaluated. It doesn't make sense to return anything. You can either log the content or send it to the client. An unconditional return in a loop doesn't make sense, too. The first return will leave the loop. Don't use `...Sync` functions in a server environment. `...Sync` functions will block your server application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like `path()` to better handle the filesystem side.

This could work your way:

```
const fs = require('fs') // load nodejs fs lib
const path = require('path') // load nodejs path lib
const mdPath = 'md' // name of the local dir
const data = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, mdPath)) //join the paths and let fs read the dir
console.log('file names', data) // Return Array of files
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log('file name:', data[i]) // we get each file name
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, mdPath, data[i]), 'utf-8') // join dir name, md folder path and filename and read its content
  console.log('content:\n' + fileContent) // log its content
}
```

I created a folder `./md`, containing the files `one.md, two.md, three.md`. The code above logs their content just fine.

```
>> node .\foo.js
file names [ 'one.md', 'three.md', 'two.md' ]
file name: one.md
content:
# one

file name: three.md
content:
# three

file name: two.md
content:
# two
```

Note that there is no error handling for anything that could go wrong with reading files.